# Fastify not recognizing custom request

Tags: typescript, types, request, backend, fastify

I'm currently learning backend and I am working on a Node TypeScript project using Fastify. I am facing the following problem:

```
Argument of type '(request: PasswordRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouteHandlerMethod<RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, RouteGenericInterface, unknown, FastifySchema, FastifyTypeProviderDefault, FastifyBaseLogger>'.
  Types of parameters 'request' and 'request' are incompatible.
    Type 'FastifyRequest<RouteGenericInterface, RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, FastifySchema, FastifyTypeProviderDefault, unknown, FastifyBaseLogger, ResolveFastifyRequestType<...>>' is not assignable to type 'PasswordRequest'.
      Type 'RouteGenericInterface' is not assignable to type '{ Body: { oldPassword: string; newPassword: string; }; }'.
        Types of property 'Body' are incompatible.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ oldPassword: string; newPassword: string; }'.

56     instance.post("/password", { onRequest: [authentificationMiddleware()] }, async(request: PasswordRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
                                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And here is the PasswordRequest type and the function where I'm using it:

```
type PasswordRequest = FastifyRequest<{
    Body: {
        oldPassword: string,
        newPassword: string
    }
}>;

...
    instance.post("/password", { onRequest: [authentificationMiddleware()] }, async(request: PasswordRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
        const infos = SecurityHelpers.getUserInfos(request);
        const { oldPassword, newPassword } = request.body;
        const updater = await UserServices.changePassword(infos, oldPassword, newPassword);
        reply.status(httpStatus.OK).send(updater);
    });
...
```

Any help on that problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generics issue while using Fastify with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620384/generics-issue-while-using-fastify-with-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

This question can be a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620384/generics-issue-while-using-fastify-with-typescript)

can you try

```
    instance.post<{ Body: PasswordRequest }>("/password", { onRequest: [authentificationMiddleware()] }, async(request: PasswordRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
        const infos = SecurityHelpers.getUserInfos(request);
        const { oldPassword, newPassword } = request.body;
        const updater = await UserServices.changePassword(infos, oldPassword, newPassword);
        reply.status(httpStatus.OK).send(updater);
    });
```

Comment: I've tried this, and got approximately the same problem: ```Type 'FastifyRequest<{ Body: { oldPassword: string; newPassword: string; }; }, RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, FastifySchema, FastifyTypeProviderDefault, unknown, FastifyBaseLogger, ResolveFastifyRequestType<...>>' is missing the following properties from type '{ oldPassword: string; newPassword: string; }': oldPassword, newPassword``` here is the last line of the error message

Comment: use type type def as PasswordRequest = {
        oldPassword: string,
        newPassword: string
    } and then try above solution